# My Float keep rounded in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Please help me..

```
TextView txt;
txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tes);
float x=7/2;
txt.setText(String.format("%.2f",x));
```

why the result is "3"..??? i need 3.5... i've tried BigDecimal, DecimalFormat or anything. the result all same.. where is my comma...???

Comment: @AndrewBrooke if int rmax=35; how to type it? x=rmaxf/2?

Comment: Cast it. `x = (float) rmax / 2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

7 and 2 are Integers. You need to declare them to be float/double, too, for this to work.

Try:

```
float x = 7f / 2f;
```

Answer (score 0):

7/2 - here 7 and 2 are integers. you are assigning the result to float which will be a integer value. If you want 3.5 convert 7 and 2 explicitly to float/double and store it in float/double you will get 3.5.